# email confirmation with omniauth-identity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using `omniauth` and `devise` for login with Facebook. I would like to allow for a new identity with email and password. It seems that `omniauth-identity` is the right option.

But I can't find out whether `omniauth-identity` supports email confirmation (i.e., sending a confirmation with a link to validate email). So my questions are:

How should I add `confirmable` feature from `devise` to `omniauth-identify`?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd use Devise.

Out of the box it provides username/password authentication, with all of the usual stuff like email confirmation, password resets, changing passwords, user lock-outs etc.

You can then easily hook in your omniauth plugins straight into Devise, so that you can allow users to log in with Facebook (for example) *or* a username and password.

There's a great tutorial about using Devise with omniauth-facebook on the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview).

My advice - don't try and roll your own auth. Devise has a few years of maturity behind it and many many contributors that make it awesome!

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks RiPuk. I am using both `Devise` and `Omniauth` for my app, but up to now I turn off email features in Devise. Now, I just want to use `omniauth-confirmable' in Devise on `omniauth-identity`. (See my update)

Comment: OK, if you've already got Devise set up then you don't need omniauth-identify. I'm not that familiar with it, but it looks like a basic username/password setup, which is what Devise does. I'd ditch omniauth-confirmable and test your basic Devise setup works properly. Once you've confirmed that, then enable the `confirmable` module, and test that works. Then, when you're happy with that, enable `omniauth-facebook`. One other thing to note - you'll need to set your omniauth controller up in such a way that users that log in with Facebook are automatically confirmed (using the `.confirm!` method)